# How to scale an object according to window size?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, shapes

I am trying to create a shape inside of a JPanel, and as the JPanel increases and decreases the size of the shape also changes accordingly.

```
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawLine(0,100,50,0);
   }
```

My problem is that I don't know how to scale it using something along the lines of this.getHeight() or this.getLength().

Answer (score 3):

Besides the path outlined by @MadProgrammer, there are two other ways I can think of to scale graphics.

Swing components can generally rely on the `Graphics` object actually being a `Graphics2D` object.

1. We can then use [`Graphics2D.scale(sx,sy)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#scale%28double,%20double%29).
2. A scale instance of an `AffineTransform` (obtained using [`getScaleInstance(sx,sy)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getScaleInstance%28double,%20double%29).  Set it to the `Graphics2D` before drawing.

Using either method, the original co-ordinates will be scaled as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean you want to maintain a proportional ratio as the component size changes...

There are a few ways to do this...

You could start by determining the "default" values, that is, if the "preferred" width was `200`, the line start point would 50% of the width and the end point would be 25% of the width.

This would allow you to do something like...

```
int width = getWidth();
int x1 = (int)(Math.round(width * 0.5d);
int x2 = (int)(Math.round(width * 0.25d);
g.drawLine(0, x1, x2, 0);
```